# Proper way to import delegate protocols

Tags: ios, import, header, protocols

I try to import as very little as possible in my header files (using the implementation file instead), and for classes we can use @class, but what about protocols?  If I try to declare a protocol that I'll be using in that header with @protocol I get a warning that "Cannot find protocol definition for '...'"

Is the proper way to handle this simply by importing the header that does the protocol declaration?  (so one .h file imports the other .h)

Example for ListViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JTRevealSidebarV2Delegate.h"  // is this the best way?

@class List;

@protocol JTRevealSidebarV2Delegate;  // this produces a warning.

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, JTRevealSidebarV2Delegate>
```

Comment: "I try to import as very little as possible" - you shouldn't. Better give the compiler more info than less.

Comment: In the header file I mean.  I import everything in the .m and just have @class declarations in the header for any custom classes imported in the implementation file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct, but if you want to get picky you can always create a single .h file where you declare your protocol only, and have both your `ListViewController` and `JTRevealSidebarV2Delegate` import it

Comment: I thought about doing that but it seemed a little overkill.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need the `#import`. `@protocol` doesn't give the compiler enough information to do its type checking.

(When you declare a property of type `List` all it needs to know is that you really mean `List` and not, say, `Lisp`. A pointer to any object is the same size. A protocol, on the other hand, contains a list of stuff that a class needs to do. It needs to know what "stuff" is to do anything useful.)

Comment: Right, the class I was declaring there (List) has nothing to do with the protocol in this particular instance.  I was just showing how I would forward declare a class & was wondering if there was something similar for protocols.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Steps to do

1. make a protocol.h file declare your @optional methods etc
2. in your class A import protocol.h and implement the methods.
3. Use reference of the calss A's obj to call its methods of protocol from any place.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, I just was trying to figure out the best place to import.  Since I usually import in the .m file I wasn't sure if there was a way to forward declare the protocol & not import in the header.

Comment: Forward declaration just tells the class type to the compiler its ok if you dont want to implement any method.But if you want to do more compiler needs more information and thus you have to import the file.Dont worry import is already optimized unlike include